# What is the use of loop.call_exception_handler(context)

Tags: python-asyncio

Kindly help to provide one sample usage of loop.call_exception_handler(context) with an example in asyncio. When loop.get_exception_handler() is already present, why do someone need to call the exception handler explicitly. Also if loop.get_exception_handler() is not set, then what do loop.call_exception_handler(context) call.

Answer (score 0):

`call_exception_handler` is a convenience function that encapsulates the logic of invoking the custom exception handler or the default exception handler, and of falling back to the default exception handler if the custom one itself fails. It is designed to be called from code that encounters an exception but doesn't have a "caller" to propagate it to. For example:

- The handle that implements `call_soon` and `call_later` catches exceptions while invoking the provided function and uses `call_exception_handler` to report it.
- The server part of the event loop code that calls `accept` in a loop uses `call_exception_handler` to report exceptions raised by `accept`. It cannot propagate the exception to its caller because it is running in a background task, so it has no caller.
- Various parts of transports use `call_exception_handler` to report errors.

> When loop.get_exception_handler() is already present, why do someone need to call the exception handler explicitly.

Because `get_exception_handler()` only invokes the custom exception handler, **if one is set**. If one is not set, the default exception handler is returned. And if one is set, and it raises an exception, the default exception handler is used to report *that* exception. And errors like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` are carefully ignored. It would be tedious and error-prone to repeat this logic in every place that needs to invoke the exception handler, so `call_exception_handler` was created.